Mapping elements of union type to corresponding handler functions in Typescript
I am currently trying to map data payload types (with no fields strictly in common except their type field) to handler functions to be called when a payload of that format is received. The dictionary I am using to do this is written similar to this:
type Request = | RequestA | RequestB;

type RequestA = {
    type: 'typeA',
    propA: string,
    prop1: number
};

// RequestA and RequestB have differing subtypes
type RequestB = {
    type: 'typeB',
    propB: { val: string },
    prop2: string
};

const requestHandlers: { [E in Request as E["type"]]: ((r: E) => void) | undefined } = {
    'typeA': (a: RequestA) => null,
    'typeB': (b: RequestB) => null,
};

This seems to make sense to me in theory, and there are no errors with the declaration of requestHandlers as it stands, but when I try to index the dictionary with a variable of the generic Request type, I get the following error:
Argument of type 'Request' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'RequestA & RequestB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'RequestA' is not assignable to type 'never'.

For the following code:
const payload: RequestA = {
    type: 'typeA',
    propA: "hello",
    prop1: 3
};

if (requestHandlers[payload.type] !== undefined) {
    requestHandlers[payload.type]!(payload);
}                                  ~~~~~~~

Clearly the r: E parameter in the mapped type definition is being converted into an intersection because it varies between request types. I would like the function to behave more as a union while still providing a strict relation between request types and handler functions with a request parameter appropriate for the corresponding type. Basically, I want the dictionary to function as written, even with generic Request indexing.
Maybe a different approach entirely would be better, but I can't think of one.
I did find this answer which solves a problem similar to mine, but the solution is to employ the generic any type for handler parameters which is less than ideal for my use case.

Please [edit] so that the code is a [mre] without pseudocode like ... and etc, and where everything we need is defined (e.g., is WSS something we care about? If so we need its definition; if not it shouldn't be mentioned.) It should be easy for us to copy and paste the code into our own IDE without having to try to pull apart intervening text and commenting out pseudocode. This is quite likely going to be an instance of ms/TS#30581 and there are approaches to deal with it, but if it's too hard to get started then I don't know if I can.

(see prev comment) Trying to use some of your code from your answer below, I get this approach. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer after the relevant [mre] appears in the question. If not, what's missing?

Thanks for the comments! I've updated my answer below with your solution because it looks cleaner to me.

• This update to the question still isn't a [mre] because we need code not provided here... like Server, Client, RequestType2Format1, etc. •  You've used my solution in your answer? What possessed you to do that? Why not let me write the answer with my own solution, explaining it, as I said?

I've updated my post, hopefully it is more clear now. Your approach was very informative for similar problems I've encountered so feel free to write something up yourself, I think it would be very helpful.

I think maybe you're not understanding what a [mre] is. We should be able to take your code and copy it and paste it into our own IDEs and your problem should be immediately apparent without distractions. Right now, if I do that with your current code, I get errors because handlerA, handlerB, and payload and even this are not defined.  Do you understand the issue and can you [edit] the code accordingly?  Or is it still not clear what I'm asking for?

Have you tried using an IDE here? It's still not demonstrating what you're trying to demonstrate. You want payload to be of type Request, right, like this?

• Have you tried using an IDE here? It's still not demonstrating what you're trying to demonstrate. You want payload to be of type Request, right, like this? Maybe you could make that change? • If so, given the current version of the code, I'd suggest this approach which is ms/TS#30581 and the recommended solution at ms/TS#47109. Let me know if you want to see that as an answer.
